# SwiftUI NavigationLink View in .toolbar(...): unwanted nested child views on model change

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two views:

1. Main view with Navigation link to User's settings page
2. User SettingsView, which allows to change user's settings (username)

```
struct User: Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var username: String
}

class Store: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User? = User(id: 1, username: "foo")
    
    func updateUser(to newUsername: String) {
        user?.username = newUsername
    }
}

@main
struct PlaygoundApp: App {
    @StateObject var store = Store()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(store)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text("Username: \(store.user?.username ?? "")")
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SettingsView(user: store.user),
                    label: {
                        Text("Edit user")
                    })
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    var user: User?
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(user?.username ?? "")
        Button(action: {
            store.updateUser(to: "New username")
        }, label: {
            Text("Update username")
        })
    }
}
```

Here's how it works:

[image]

But I put NavigationLink button to Toolbar, each model change creates a new navigational view:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Home View")
            Text("Username: \(store.user?.username ?? "")")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HomeView()
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        if (store.user != nil) {
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: SettingsView(user: store.user),
                                label: {
                                    Text("Edit user")
                                })
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what happening:

[image]

How to aviod nested view creation?

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand what the problem is. Can you elaborate a bit further?